# I want to callback method without return by coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I write bellow code.

```
initialize : ->
@model.apiForecast = new ApiForecastModel(
  model: @model.get('apiForecast')
)
@model.forecast = new ForecastModel(
  model: @model.get('forecast')
)
cookie = Cookie()
forecastCall = this.model.forecast.fetch(
  data:
    token: cookie['Authorization']
  headers:
    Authorization: cookie['Authorization']
  success: ->
    console.log('Success Forecast')
  error: (e) ->
    console.log('Service request failure: ' + e)
)

$.when( forecastCall )
.done( () -> (
    @getApiForecast()
    return
  ).bind(@)
  return
)
return
```

But Then I got this error.

> error: unexpected indentation

Actually, I want to compile to ajax code like this.

```
$.when( forecastCall ).done(
  function () {
    this.getApiForecast();
  }.bind(this)
);
```

Do you have any resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have your parentheses in the wrong place for that `bind` call to work. You want to wrap the entire anonymous function in parentheses, not just the function's body:

```
$.when( forecastCall )
.done( ( ->
    @getApiForecast()
    return
).bind(@))
```

Or better (or at least less noisy), use an `=>` function and let CoffeeScript take care of the binding:

```
$.when( forecastCall ).done( =>
  @getApiForecast()
  return
)
```

---

I'm assuming that all the code in your question is actually inside `initialize`.